# Div over 2 other divs?

Tags: html, css

[image]

What's the best way to add `div3` as shown in image? Should it be separate `div` or child of `div1` or `div2`?

Im not entirely sure how to make it so that I can easily manipulate `div3` in different screen sizes. I somehow feel that setting `div` position to `absolute` and use huge offsets is wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you would use absolute positioning to place the third `div`. There are a few ways to do this, I think this one will be the easiest to understand.

```css
#container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
div.green{
  background: green;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
div.red{
  background: red;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
div.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  }

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  }

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  right: 5%;
  background: rgba(45,45,45,.25);
  }
```

```html
<div class="div1">Div1
<div class="div3">Div3</div>
</div>
<div class="div2">Div2</div>
```

Put that div 3 in div 1, then set div 1 to position:relative, then div3 to position:absolute. Then you can position div3 in relation to div1. Div3 will be out of the flow of the document and as such won't know about div1 and div2 so you'll need to adjust for that as div1 and div2 get smaller (content will start to get covered by div3).

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways.

One is like you said ,setting it as absolute. But make it as child of second div which will be relative, and add negative top to it.

Second one is to use negative marings on it and second div. But looking at these 2 options, first one is just fine from the "best practices" point.

Here is the code:

```css
.first,.second {
  width:100%;
  background:#000;
  height:80px;
}
.second {
  position:relative;
  background:#888;
}
.third {
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  right:50px;
  top:-20px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
</div>
<div class="second">
  <div class="third">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is add it as a new separated div, since it is not contained completely in any of the two other divs.

About the use of the absolute position, it is designed for this kind of use, so do not feel awkward for use it. For keep a good design for different screen sizes, I recommend you to use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) so you can adapt your Css for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

without using position `absolute` or `relative`.

```css
.bigdiv {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.smalldiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  float: right;
  margin-right:10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /*
  you can use margin-top:-50px; for browser compatibility
  margin top shoult be -(half of div height);
  
  */
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='bigdiv'>
  </div>
  <div class='smalldiv'>
  </div>
  <div class='bigdiv'>
  </div>

</div>
```